# Failing to specialize function for function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am using VS2015 Update 3.  I have a function that I desire to specialize based on the return type of a callable object.  When the callable object is a functor, everything works as expected.  When the callable object is a function or a function pointer, it fails to specialize the overloaded function.  I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I haven't done anything with SFINAE in over a year.

What am I missing that is causing the specialization failure?

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    T mOp;
    template <typename = void>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            std::remove_cv_t<
                std::remove_reference_t<
                    decltype(mOp())
                >
            >,
            void
        >::value
    >::type func()
    {
        std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename = void>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            std::remove_cv_t<
                std::remove_reference_t<
                    decltype(mOp())
                >
            >,
            bool
        >::value
    >::type func()
    {
        std::cout << "void" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
auto createS(T&& t)
{
    return S<T>{ t };
}

void vfunc()
{
}
bool bfunc()
{
    return true;
}
struct vfunctor
{
    void operator()()
    {
    }
};
struct bfunctor
{
    bool operator()()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

void func()
{
    createS(bfunc).func();     // Fails to specialize func()
    createS(vfunc).func();     // Fails to specialize func()
    createS(vfunctor{}).func();
    createS(bfunctor{}).func();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of this works, because substitution failure is only a failure in the immediate context of the substitution - and you're trying to SFINAE in a context that doesn't depend on the immediate function template parameters. Your constraints in `func()` are based on the *class* template parameters, not the local function template parameters, so those are just a hard error.

The easiest way to do this is via tag dispatching. Wrap `decltype(mOp())` into a tag type and then just overload:

```
template <class T> struct tag { };

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    T mOp;

    void func() {
        func_impl(tag<std::decay_t<decltype(mOp())>>{});
    }

    void func_impl(tag<bool> ) { std::cout << "bool\n"; }        
    void func_impl(tag<void> ) { std::cout << "void\n"; }        
};
```

---

If you need `func()` to be SFINAE-friendly itself for some reason, then you can introduce a new template parameter to just fake out the original one:

```
template <class..., class U=T>
auto func()
    -> decltype(func_impl(tag<std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<U>>>{}))
{
    return func_impl(tag<std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<U>>>{});
}
```

Note that this has to appear *after* the declarations of the various `func_impl` overloads.